# unable to download a software in ubuntu due to permission denied

Tags: terminal, sudo, apt-get

```
cpp@pachoriya:~$ apt-get install pitivi
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

unable to download a software due to permission denied. How can i install this package?

Comment: Well, are you root? (This is not on topic on this site, though.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root

Answer (score 1):

Installing a software package needs root priviliges. Use `sudo`

`sudo apt-get install pitivi`

or switch to root user using `sudo -s`, then install the packages.

Related read: https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user